# How do I focus a button through [id*= "button name"]

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to keep focus on a button with a modal I was successful in doing so with this line of code:

```
$("[id*=btnAddEditExecutive]").focus();
```

The problem is whenever user clicks a textbox and clicks out `($("[id*=btnAddEditExecutive]"))` loses focus.

So I am trying to use:

```
document.getElementById("[id*=btnAddEditExecutive]").focus();
```

But it will not work.

Please help! Thanks!

EDIT: 
I have edited my code accordingly it still does not work.

```
 $("#addEditExecutive").dialog({
            modal: true,
        width: 800,
        appendTo: "form",
        open: function () {
            $(this).keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) { // the enter key
                    $("[id*=btnAddEditExecutive]").click(function () {
                        // do stuff
                    })
                }
            });
},
        buttons: {
            "Add/Edit Executive Information": function () {

                $("[id*=btnAddEditExecutive]").click();
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel ?")) {
                    //code if yes
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }

            }
        },
```

Comment: Um, it is impossible to have more than one thing focused at a time...What is the goal?

Comment: It's pretty unclear what the workflow is supposed to be.

Comment: I have a submit button titled [id*=btnAddEditExecutive]. I am trying to keep focus on this button even when users click in and out of text boxes on the modal.

Comment: If you continually set focus on a single element, you'd be disrupting the user's ability to interact.

Comment: I want focus to return to the button after a user has clicked out of the text box

Comment: the goal is so that if the user accidentally hits enter it clicks this button "[id*=btnAddEditExecutive]"

Comment: If you want that to happen you should intercept the 'enter' keycode and react properly.

Comment: `document.getElementById()` expects an ID, not a selector expression.

Comment: Agree to @JayBlanchard. You're trying to adapt a _solution_ that's not exactly the right solution to your problem. You should approach it in a different way.

Comment: You are way confused.  First, as MelanciaUK says, getElementById requires the raw ID, you're putting a css selector there.  You would do something like document.getElementById("btnAddEditExecutive") to find it.  However, you're lucky your code doesn't work.  You are really confused about input focus.  If you force the focus on that button then folks will be unable to interact with other fields.

Comment: Understood. I have very poor js knowledge :/ 
Thanks for your input thus far gentlemen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the button to be clicked when the enter key is clicked -

```
$('<your selector>').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) { // the enter key
    $('[id*=btnAddEditExecutive]').click(function() {
        // do stuff
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to amend my code accordingly, but it still is not functioning.

Comment: Check the value of 'this' in your code - it might not be what you expect.

Comment: changed it to: "#addEditExecutive". doesn't fire.

Comment: Add a console.log() to see if the click fires.

Answer (score 0):

resolved it with this line of code:

```
            $(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first').focus();
            $(this).keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
                    $("[id*=btnAddEditExecutive]").click();
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -2):

Change your code to this - `$('div[id=nameid]').focus();`
Or (if don't work) do - `if ($('div').attr('id') == 'nameid') { do something };`